# Codeigniter transaction query cannot rollback

Tags: codeigniter

I can input data type date with string

```
$data = array(
            'date_added' => $this->input->post('category')
            );
            $this->um->add_data($data);
            redirect('/subcategory');
```

but why invalid data cannot rollback, value data still insert to my table

```
function add_data($data){
        $this->db->trans_begin();
        $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data); 
        if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }else{
            $this->db->trans_commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try replacing `$this->db->trans_begin;` with this `$this->db->trans_start();`.

Comment: i following [https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/transactions.html) in sub category 'Running Transactions Manually'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function add_data($data){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data); 
    $this->db->trans_complete();
}
```

It will make automatically rollback your transaction if there's something wrong in your input process.

Reference [Here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/db_driver_reference.html?highlight=trans_start#CI_DB_driver::trans_start)

Comment: record still insert into my table with value nothing

Comment: i update my model just like this

`function add_data($data){
  $this->db->trans_begin();
  
  $this->db->insert('subcategory', $data); 
  
  $this->db->trans_complete();
  
  if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE){
   $this->db->trans_rollback();
   return FALSE;
  }else{
   $this->db->trans_commit();
   return TRUE;
  }
 }`


when date type input string, record still insert into table cannot roll back and return value is TRUE.

Comment: Are you sure the variable name and field name in the db table correct?